# Got multiple copies of same row in Cassandra when doing kafka-spark streaming

Tags: multithreading, cassandra, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I wrote a Kafka-spark consumer to write the messages from kafka into cassandra db. There are 24 partitions in the kafka topic. There is 2 MB message sent every 5 minutes  with 9000 rows every batch.
I am adding an additional system timestamp column to the message data and storing in cassandra.
I found that there are multiple entries for the same message with different timestamp values with different key. Does this imply that my kafka threading is not working correctly?
Please let me know if you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns in your question. What version of Kafka? What version of spark? Are you using Recievers or the direct api or something custom? How is data being produced ? Are you sure duplicate messages aren't being sent at different timestamps?